# Using a div as a clipping mask in css

Tags: html, css, overlay, mask, clipping

I have a background image that has background-size:cover; applied to it and then a series of divs overlaid which I would like to become individual clipping masks.

I've looked at the feature clip: rect(20px, 20px, 20px, 20px,); however as the divs are brought in through a CMS system, it will be inappropriate to define set sizes.

Is there a way of setting the div with a clipping mask property so that it clips the image anywhere the div is placed on the page?

I don't particularly want to use an image overlay either as this site will be responsive.

Comment: Update: Ok, so I've found the element background-clip: content-box; which in a way does what I need for making the divs become a clipping mask but this only works if the background image is part of the div.

Can this be extended so the background-clip is applied to the parent div?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you're simply looking for an overlay that will resize with the screen size, and the div with the background image?

In that case, if possible, why not simply append these divs INSIDE the div that needs clipping, like [this](http://jsbin.com/ejirob/4/edit). For this sample purpose I only used one div with a transparent background and a border applied to it. If you need to clip the image in a non-rectangular shape, you will need more divs (ex. for parallelogram, diamond, triangle shape, you'll need at least 2).

Also, sadly CSS doesn't allow for % borders, but I think this example is

You can also do it the other way around and place your img div inside the clipper divs; just a matter of what fits best...

```css
body, html { 
  /* necessary for sizing children in % */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#tobeClipped {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/infocus/ngpc112812/s_n01_nursingm.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
#tobeClipped>div {
  position: absolute;
}
#clippers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 20px solid grey;
  border-left-width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="tobeClipped">
    <div id="clippers"></div>
</div>
```

Please do clarify if this was not at all what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `clip-path` CSS property can be applied to all HTML elements, SVG graphic elements and SVG container elements:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: this is a dodgy link