# Is it possible to clip a side of a DIV with CSS like so?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms, bookiza

I have a parent and a child `div` with ids and dimensions as described in the following diagram:

```
<div id="clip"> 
  <div id="page"> 
     <!-- Content/Images here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The dimensions of the parent and child divs are like so:

```
#clip {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1414px;
}

#page {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 707px; 
}
```

Now I want to skew a side off from the child `div` at an `angle ø` and clip the right side of the `div`, like so:

[image: clipped page]

Is it possible to do so with CSS alone?

> Constraints: Cannot use the triangular border hack, the content inside the #page child `div` cannot be skewed, and the less hack-ey the solution, the better it is for everything. I was hoping this could be done with just CSS3 transformations but I couldn't find a way so far.

Answer by @ksav is close but it is still using obscuration technique with a pseudo :before element with absolute position. It doesn't let me *disappear* the clipped part of div#page so that it can look something like this:

[image: clipped div must disappear and not be obscured]

Comment: You can put another div as overlay on top of the div with the text. And then rotate that div a certain degree.

Comment: Using pseudo class will work as well indeed!

Comment: No, no I can't obscure the two divs with anything else. It just has to disappear…

Comment: This site may help you. http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228331/using-a-div-as-a-clipping-mask-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use -webkit-clip-path

```
#clip {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1414px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#page {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 707px; 
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 40% 0, 29% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/rollinglex/pen/ZMNvjY

I found this site to be vey useful: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

regarding using js and css, this article should help: https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/

Comment: Interesting! How did you evaluate the polygon values above? Can we set `polygon(0 0, x% 0, x-1% 100%, 0% 100%) ` using a generic angle ø and not hardcode the values into the css? I'll be using javascript to calculate ø and apply the x values on the `div` directly.

Comment: Be sure to check the support for `clip-path` before proceeding. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
 height: 1000px;
  width: 707px; 
}

.content:before {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 110%;
  transform: skewX(-5deg) translateX(10%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras imperdiet congue aliquam. Etiam efficitur lectus id nulla iaculis dapibus. Phasellus nec nisl bibendum, hendrerit diam at, consequat est. In posuere lorem eget felis venenatis elementum.
    Ut vestibulum a nulla commodo pharetra. Cras accumsan dui a libero faucibus rutrum. Integer sed nunc accumsan, convallis lectus venenatis, iaculis arcu. Pellentesque tincidunt purus eu pulvinar tempus. Nam aliquet orci vel sapien condimentum pharetra.
    In rhoncus vehicula metus, vitae euismod mauris consequat sit amet. Praesent suscipit quam libero, eget semper neque aliquet faucibus.</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/vzwdKz)

Comment: How did you arrive at translateX(30%) when skewing by skewX(5%). Can we do this for a generic angle ø? Also the paragraph tag has to go inside `div#clipper` here.

Comment: The translateX is simply to move it from left to right, measured from the `translate-origin` which has been set to `bottom left`. You can apply any angle you like to skewX(). Stick to negative values to achieve the desired effect. Also, i've edited the above solution so that you only need a single div.

Comment: Interesting!… thanks for sharing the experiment on Codepen. I'll dive into it there.

Comment: In this approach we're still obscuring the `div#content` with a :before pseudo element. To make it work I'll have to dial up `alpha` to value `1` in the  `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)`; property of pseudo element. What I need to be able to do instead is make the clipped side of DIV disappear completely. So that I can show the background of the HTML page under it i.e. the root of webpage..

Comment: I updated the question with an expected result.

Comment: The solution from @Meeses is the way to go then (unless you need to support IE/Edge, in which case you might need to revisit).

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#parent{
  background: #fff333;
}
#child{
  background: #aaaccc;
  left: 30%;
  transform: skewX(-8deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

</div>
<div id="child">
  
</div>
```

Yes it is possible and here is a rough idea how to do it. I am sure it is not the best solution but it works.