Man walking into a mountain hole transition
I have 3 divs, let's call them 'man', 'hole' and 'mountain'
Hole is layered over mountain at the bottom middle (like an enterance)
Man has an index higher than the hole so when his position increase he appears to walk into it.
When man reaches top of the hole, he should go under the mountain.
So, mountain needs to be under hole which is under man,
but man needs to be above hole and under mountain.
Has anyone got any suggestions for ways of making this work.
Current considerations was to create 2 different mountains. The standard one at the bottom and a second one at the top which is cropped.
This works, okay. However, the hold has a border radius of 50% so it isn't a clean transition when the man goes in. Anyone got any better ideas?
Here is a rough example:


.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.outer-mask {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 4;
}

.hole-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%) rotate(180deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

.hole {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.farmer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: -30px;
    bottom: -10px; /* adjust here to see effect */
    right: -36%;
    font-size: 50px;
}
<div class="outer">
    <div class="outer-mask"></div>
    <div class="hole-wrapper">
        <div class="hole"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="farmer">‍</div>





Please click [edit], then [<>] and post a [mcve]. We want to see code too

Would probably make more sense, if you created the shape of your mountain with a hole in it, using a clippath. Then the green background for the hole and the man can be layered behind it.

Done, just adjust the farmers top to see the rough effect

Are you looking for a CSS-only solution to this? Various methods would be: 1) Using PNGs, with alpha for transparent areas; 2) SVG shapes (which you can define in the code rather than using external files, if preferable); 3) CSS masking; 4) CSS clip-path. It can be solved using any of these methods, but don't want to guess at any preferences or other requirements you might have. 3 + 4 are cool because they work with CSS only, but 1 + 2 are ultimately more maintainable/versatile, if you ever want more design on your mountain, tunnel, etc! (More complex shape, texture, etc.)

@Snor yes, CSS only would be my preference. I've never seen clip-path or masking before, let me looking into them

Does the man always walk direct, straight up, into the mountain as you have shown, or might he come from the side, or diagonally? I ask, because those possibilities would require a bit more sophistication to make sure he's in front of the mountain to begin with then partially behind it (possibly all 3 states, in front/in the hole/behind the mountain, at once).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483173/is-it-possible-to-clip-a-side-of-a-div-with-css-like-so and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/ for clip-path examples. SVG would also be powerful here.

Let's place a div over the upper part of the hole to cover whatever passed under it. It's shape, though, should be inverted semi circle. The way to do it is using radial background.


.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.outer-mask {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hole-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.hole {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.farmer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: -30px;
  bottom: -10px;
  /* adjust here to see effect */
  right: -36%;
  font-size: 50px;
  animation: moveMargin 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, transparent 49px, red 49px);
  background-size: 100% 100px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes moveMargin {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: -120px;
  }
}
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-mask"></div>
  <div class="hole-wrapper">
    <div class="hole"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="farmer">‍</div>
</div>



